# UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBean Already exists after application "re"start

Tags: java, webserver, weblogic, connection-pooling

When I deploy an `application.war` that contains a servlet to my weblogic server it runs fine. The servlet uses an instance of `UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBean` and starts up without any problems.

In the administration console I use the "stop when work completes" command and in my `destroy()` method it calls:

```
UniversalConnectionPoolManagerImpl.getUniversalConnectionPoolManager()
                .startConnectionPool(mConnectionPoolName);
```

When I then click on "start servicing requests" command in the administration console I get this exception:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Unable to start the Universal Connection Pool: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to start the Universal Connection Pool: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: MBean exception occurred while registering or unregistering the MBean
at com.exzac.dal.jdbc.Database.getConnection(Database.java:134)
at com.exzac.dal.jdbc.Database.executeQuery(Database.java:161)
at com.exzac.profilesystem.ProfileSystemConfiguration.retrieveConfigurationTable(ProfileSystemConfiguration.java:214)
... 49 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to start the Universal Connection Pool:     java.sql.SQLException: Unable to start the Universal Connection Pool: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: MBean exception occurred while registering or unregistering the MBean
at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newSQLException(UCPErrorHandler.java:541)
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.throwSQLException(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:587)
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.startPool(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:276)
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:646)
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:613)
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:607)
at com.exzac.dal.jdbc.Database.getConnection(Database.java:132)
... 51 more
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to start the Universal Connection Pool: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: MBean exception occurred while registering or unregistering the MBean
at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newSQLException(UCPErrorHandler.java:541)
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.throwSQLException(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:587)
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.startPool(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:247)
... 55 more
 Caused by: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: MBean exception occurred while registering or unregistering the MBean
at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:421)
at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:389)
at oracle.ucp.admin.UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBeanImpl.getUniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBean(UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBeanImpl.java:149)
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.startPool(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:242)
... 55 more
 Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: oracle.ucp.admin:name=UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBean
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at oracle.ucp.admin.UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBeanImpl.getUniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBean(UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBeanImpl.java:136)
... 56 more
 Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: oracle.ucp.admin:name=UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBean
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:453)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.internal_addObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1484)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:963)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:917)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:312)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:482)
at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$27.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:714)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.registerMBean(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:709)
at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXContextInterceptor.registerMBean(JMXContextInterceptor.java:448)
at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$27.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:712)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.registerMBean(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:709)
at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServer.registerMBean(WLSMBeanServer.java:462)
at oracle.ucp.admin.UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBeanImpl$2.run(UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBeanImpl.java:142)
... 58 more
```

From then on I hit this exception, even when I stop the server and restart and try to deploy. Only cleaning all published resources seems to clear the exception. I understand that a published resource was not properly cleaned in the destroy method, and I am thinking that the resource is the `UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBean` instance, but I thought it would be clean up by the `destroyConnectionPool` method:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/e11990/oracle/ucp/admin/UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBean.html#destroyConnectionPool_java_lang_String_

How do I avoid hitting this exception?

Just as an interesting (yet unsafe) workaround: For some reason when I insert this into the initialization:

```
 try {
     UniversalConnectionPoolManagerImpl.getUniversalConnectionPoolManager().destroyConnectionPool(mConnectionPoolName);
     } catch (final Exception e1) {
     LOGGER.error(e1);

     }
```

the exception is thrown and caught saying that it could not find a `connectionPool` with this name to destroy, but the original problem is gone. `javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: oracle.ucp.admin:name=UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBean` is not thrown

Answer (score 1):

This bug seems to have been fixed in versions 11.2.0.4 and 12.1.0.2. I couldn't find any documentation about it, but for me the error disappeared with the above mentioned versions.

JDBC/UCP Download Page:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

Answer (score 0):

This is from Oracle's 11.2.0.4 UCP.jar README.txt.

### Fixes in 11.2.0.4

16805157  The name of the UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBean is made
          unique per classloader and hence unique to every UCP instance
          even within the same JVM

This fixes the javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException described in the original question. Every connection pool created with have a unique name and will not result in InstanceAlreadyExistsException. However, since you are restarting, you should look into figuring out how to close the connection pool MBean cleanly so you won't run into this problem.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you are making a citation. Please consider expanding your answer so to include the source and author of the original quote. Also, considering making it clear how it does address the OP problem. Thank you!

Comment: Hey, are you trying to add a citation to your own question with a registered account? It showed up in the Suggested Edits queue.

Comment: If both accounts belong to you then you might want to request that they be merged over on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) once you get 5 rep.